# Return value from previous row in regex

Tags: regex

I am looking to return a specific group in the previous row via regex.

Suppose I have the following information and the target is to extract the value **90** on the basis of the differentiation in the following line.

```
QTY+66:90:PCE
SCC+2
DTM+45:20200416:15
QTY+66:60:PCE
SCC+3
DTM+35:20210614:2
```

If I were to traget the value **90**, I'd have to look for the `SCC+2` tag and if I were to loom for the value **60**, it would be the `SCC+3` tag.

I got this far in an attempt to return the value 90 `(?<=^QTY\+66:)(\d+)(.*\n.*SCC\+2.*)` but it seems convoluted and I fail to extract only Group 1. Here is the link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/llsjrz/1). I am using R for the actual application. Thanks for the help !

Comment: So without fanfare, its simply `.*YOURVALUE.*\r?\n.*` or is that all of it ? If not, then you need to stress the _value added highlight constants_ to do the proper delimited match. Your explanation has many holes and is unclear, and without the necessary details to do this most simplest of matches. If you say the details are there, then why the question since it appears answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
(?<=:)\d+(?=[^\d\r\n]*[\r\n]+.*SCC\+2)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/97qAwN/4). *Details*:

- `(?<=:)` - a `:` must occur immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=[^\d\r\n]*[\r\n]+.*SCC\+2)` - immediately to the right, there must be
- `[^\d\r\n]*` - any zero or more chars other than digits, CR and LF
- `[\r\n]+` - one or more CR or LF chars
- `.*SCC\+2` - any text on a line up to the rigthmost occurrence of `SCC+2`.

In R, you can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec, "(?<=:)\\d+(?=[^\\d\r\n]*[\r\n]+.*SCC\\+2)")
```

And a couple of base R approaches with `sub`:

```r
sub(".*?\\+\\d+:(\\d+)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\r\n]*SCC\\+2.*", "\\1", vec)
sub("(?s).*?\\+\\d+:(\\d+)(?-s).*\\R.*SCC\\+2(?s).*", "\\1", vec, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex 1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/97qAwN/5) and [regex 2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/97qAwN/6).

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/eBuYar):

```r
vec <- "QTY+66:90:PCE\nSCC+2\nDTM+45:20200416:15\nQTY+66:60:PCE\nSCC+3\nDTM+35:20210614:2"
sub(".*?\\+\\d+:(\\d+)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\r\n]*SCC\\+2.*", "\\1", vec)
sub("(?s).*?\\+\\d+:(\\d+)(?-s).*\\R.*SCC\\+2(?s).*", "\\1", vec, perl=TRUE)
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec, "(?<=:)\\d+(?=[^\\d\r\n]*[\r\n]+.*SCC\\+2)")
```

All yield `[1] "90"`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I just tested it and it returns the value 66 of the previous lines in both cases. I amended it a little to take the QTY+66: addition on the left as such: `(?<=QTY\+66\:)\d+(?=.*[\r\n]+.*SCC\+3)`

Comment: @Max See the code snippet I updated just now. All solutions now return `90`.